# How to randomly generate products pop-up on click in store

Tags: plugin-wp-e-commerce

[image]I need to know how to create a store where when the user clicks a particular button, a randomly selected product will appear as a pop up and can be selected for order and can be submitted as well. Kindly check the attached image.

Comment: using code this can be achieve in a few different ways, or using javascript to call a html form with php code, or call directly a php function that does the same.

Comment: Thanks for your response, how can i get this done? Can a plugin do this or i need some codes to do so? Kindly point me to the right direction.... Thanks in advance

Comment: probably there are plugins that do this, but I do not know none. I have done this already a few times but always coding, also using woocommerce hooks to get the products. This to say that I only know how to do this using code doing a custom wp widget, or a custom plugin, direct on theme functions.php or child theme, or some other option.

Comment: This takes some time (a few hours) to do the popup properly that shows a random product, and make it work with the button (elements desired). Maybe someone knows some plugin to do this instantly.

Comment: Thanks for the response once again, I need to get this done asap.....please can you put me through the use of the code and the code itself.... I just need the popup to come randomly and I can submit the order for commission

Comment: yes, I have never tried it, but by the description maybe this plugin can do something like you want. OptinMonster.

Comment: I have checked this plugin out but it can't really do this......